# How do I connect to my gaming computer with my non-gaming computer locally?

Tags: remote-desktop, desktop-computer, gaming

I want to play on my non-gaming computer (ground floor of my house) by connecting it to my gaming computer (2nd floor). I tried the teamviewer but there's a significant lag with this setup. So is there a way to eliminate the lag? Maybe connecting both of them with Ethernet or something?

Comment: Any solution is going to introduce latency.  What else have you tried other then Teamviewer?

Comment: I doubt if any remote desktop application will give adequate performance for gaming use. You _might_ just achieve sufficient performance using dedicated hardware for remote monitor, keyboard and mouse, as [this link](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/96679-remote-monitor-keyboard-and-mouse) suggests, but no guarantees.

Comment: You do want your computers in one LAN for sure and a solution that passes data entirely within LAN. With Steam games use [Steam In-Home Streaming](http://store.steampowered.com/streaming/?l=english).

Comment: ok so theres no technology yet for this problem

Answer (score 0):

TeamViewer and similar remote assistance programs aren't the best option for this because you connect to the other computer *through their servers* (mainly to avoid firewall and NAT issues), so your gaming session is send from your gaming computer to internet and then send back to your other computer.

In order to minimize lag and use the full bandwidth of your local network you need to use a remote program that use direct connections, like the integrated Remote Desktop (only for professional<sup>*</sup> versions of Windows) or some VNC variant like [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/).

Note that even with direct connections you may not get an acceptable performance since that tools are not designed for video or gaming.

<sup>*</sup> Although the Remote Desktop client is included in all versions of Windows the server is only available in professional/business/server editions, although there are [some dubious hacks](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-rdpwrapper-win10-home) to workaround this (dubious in the legal sense, the hack itself seems safe).

Comment: is there a cable where i can connect both computers so i can play without lag?

Comment: The only cables that will come close are very long video, keyboard and mouse extension cord. Even the most high-end (PCoIP) remote connections introduce lag. Otherwise all the DotA players would have supercomputers at home and just bring laptops with them!